# How to access a dynamic property: objectName.{variable}

Tags: javascript, object

i need to access

```
objectName.myID
```

but the "myID" part is dynamically generated..

how do i do this?

i tried

```
this['objectName.'+ variable]
```

i'd hate to use eval...

ps
this happens in a function (local scope) by the way..

Comment: Sorry but that's pretty basic jQuery and you don't even seem to be close. Hint: `$("#foo")`

Comment: @Álvaro sorry, Alvaro, but apparently you are not even close to the answer...

Comment: @Christoph - Well, your edit has changed the question meaning quite a little ;-)

Comment: @Álvaro no it hasn't - it just removed the ambiguity which you obviously fell for :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access [Object properties in two ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

```
o.propertyname
//or
o.["propertyname"]
```

When using the bracket notation you have to put the propertyname in quotes or else it will be interpreted as a variable name (which in your case is exactly what you want). So in your case where you have stored the name of the property as a string, the way to go would be:

```
var variable = "propertyname";
o[variable];
/* /\ variable is replace with it's string representation "propertyname" */
```

You can even call methods this way:

```
var o = {};
var functionname = 'toString';
o[functionname]();
```

You can mix both notations, your example would look like:

```
var obj = 'objectName';
var prop = 'myID';
this[obj][prop]
// or this is possible too:
this.objectName[prop]
```

Comment: hmm i thought i tried this already and it didnt work.. ill try this again.. tnx a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `propertyName` is the name of a variable holding the name of the property, for example `'myId'`, then you can use.

```
objectName[propertyName]
```

More details in the MDN : [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: sorry, but its still wrong - it should be `objectName['propertyName']` ...

Comment: @Christoph I disagree. If propertyName is a variable holding the name of the property, which should be the case if the name is dynamic, then it's the correct syntax.

Comment: With your comment added, the intend is clear. However as it currently stands, your answer implies that `propertyName` is the name of the property and not a variable, so it's very misleading. If you want to make it a community wiki your answer should be rocksolid and not as ambiguous as it currently is.