# JavaScript function arguments statements

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

My problem is: 
(only as example, must not make sense overall):

```
// make a function and pass part of the statement as argument
function ExampleFunction( argument ) {
    document.getElementById('TestID')[0].style.argument = '#f00';
}

// then later onload
ExampleFunction( background );
```

I found out that it doesn't work this way, but I can't find out how it would be right.
If someone could correct the example to send me on  my way I would be very happy and thankful.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413167/how-to-access-a-dynamic-property-objectname-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `document.getElementById` returns a single element (or null if no element is found), so not `[0]`. secondly if you want to reference a property dynamically use `[]` notation

```
// make a function and pass part of the statement as argument
function ExampleFunction( argument ) {
    document.getElementById('TestID').style[argument] = '#f00';
}

// then later onload
ExampleFunction( 'background' );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HM3mu/

Comment: ps i forgot the [0] from a different function i used to copy where it wasnt id´s. but thankyou anyway for correcting that too :)

Answer (score -1):

getElementById returns a single element and not a collection.

the correct code is:

```
document.getElementById('TestID').style.background = '#f00';
```